# Flink 1.12 docker image not found

Tags: docker, apache-flink

I run a Kubernetes cluster, and I'm attempting to upgrade the flink clusters as they come with some long awaited features in the latest release 1.12

https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/12/10/release-1.12.0.html#kubernetes-high-availability-ha-service

I take that the release is out already? When I attempt to update the image tag in the k8s deployment I only get "Back-off pulling image" messages. I have tried "1.12.0-scala_2.11", "latest" and the usual.
I have checked Docker Hub, and the latest public tags seem to be related to 1.11.x

Does anyone know if the 1.12 images are not yet publicly available?

Answer (score 4):

The 1.12 images are not yet released to docker hub, but the patch is ready. If you really cannot wait, you can do:

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/flink-docker
cd flink-docker/1.12/scala_and_java_version_of_your_choosing
docker build .
```

And then you'll have the image locally.

But I'm pretty confident this will be resolved shortly.

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use the apache/flink repository: https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/flink/tags

It is maintained by Flink committers, as mentioned in https://github.com/apache/flink-docker

Related Jira: [FLINK-20632](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-20632?focusedCommentId=17261271&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-17261271)

Comment: Does anyone know if there are plans to ever release it under the standard "flink" tag, or will from now on be strictly under "apache/flink"?

Answer (score 1):

before we can use the official image, you can just use `haydenzhou/flink:1.12.0-scala_2.11-java8` that I build recently.